# Python spotipy Oauth : Bad request

Tags: python, oauth, spotify

This is my code

```
 UserScope = 'user-library-read'
util.prompt_for_user_token(username='vulrev1',scope=UserScope,client_id="533adb3f925b488za9d3772640ec6403",client_secret='66054b185c7541fcabce67afe522449b',redirect_uri="http://127.0.0.1/callback")
lz_uri = 'spotify:artist:36QJpDe2go2KgaRleHCDTp'

spotify = spotipy.Spotify()
results = spotify.artist_top_tracks(lz_uri)

for track in results['tracks'][:10]:
    print ('track    : ' + track['name'])
```

I'm getting this

```
spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOauthError: Bad Request
```

I'm not quite sure what's going on here, is there something I need to do with the host files ? because  http://127.0.0.1 refuses to connect

Answer (score 0):

```
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username='vulrev1',scope=UserScope,client_id="533adb3f925b488za9d3772640ec6403",client_secret='66054b185c7541fcabce67afe522449b',redirect_uri="http://127.0.0.1/callback")

spotify = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
```

You have to send your token as a auth. And also i think you must change your user ID to the specific numbers where u can find at the link of your profile.